# Jquery get values from the textbox and compare to checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have two text boxes like Mobile number and email address. If **mobile number** text box have any values, then automatically **checked** following fields.

- **Communication Email**

If Email Address have any values, then checked

- **Communication Mobile**

How to do this in `JQuery`,

```
if $("#RequirementsMobileNumber")==true
{
    $('#CommunicationSMS').attr('checked',true);
}
else if $('#RequirementsEmailAddress')==true
{
    $('#CommunicationEmail').attr('checked',true);
}
else{

}
```

If i put above code getting error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the value of text boxes like this  :

```
if( $("#RequirementsMobileNumber").val()!='')
{
    $('#CommunicationSMS').attr('checked',true);
else if ($('#RequirementsEmailAddress').val()!='')
{
     $('#CommunicationEmail').attr('checked',true);
}
else{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your `if` conditionals in parentheses `()`. Then check the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) jQuery function to get the value in your input box.

```
if ($("#RequirementsMobileNumber").val().length > 0) {
    $('#CommunicationSMS').attr('checked', true);
} else if ($('#RequirementsEmailAddress').val().length > 0) {
     $('#CommunicationEmail').attr('checked', true);
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax errors

```
 if ($("#RequirementsMobileNumber").val()!=''){

    $('#CommunicationSMS').attr('checked',true);
 }
else if ($('#RequirementsEmailAddress').val()!=''){

     $('#CommunicationEmail').attr('checked',true);
} 
else{

}
```

Comment: What is `$("#RequirementsMobileNumber"==true)` ??

Comment: it shows expected '(' when i use follow code,if $('#RequirementsMobileNumber'==true)
    {
       $('#CommunicationSMS').attr('checked',true);
    } else if $('#RequirementsEmailAddress'==true)
    {
         $('#CommunicationEmail').attr('checked',true);
    }
    else{
        $('#CommunicationSMS').attr('checked',true);
        $('#CommunicationEmail').attr('checked',true);
    }